# Is there any restriction on the number of elements in a Boolean lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I'm considering the Wikipedia definition of a [Boolean lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition). Is there any restriction on the number of elements a Boolean lattice or Boolean algebra have? (I'm asking because, say, for fields the restriction is that they must have prime power order)

Also, say I want to create a 10 element Boolean algebra? What would be an example or algorithm to create it? (For groups it is easy. I could just consider $\Bbb Z_{10}$ but I can't come up with an example for a 10 element Boolean algebra)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes, I was indeed referring to restrictions due to definition

Comment: For instance, there cannot be a Boolean algebra with $3$ elements.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks. But I was looking for a similar theorem for the general case. For which $n\in\Bbb N$, can I construct a Boolean algebra? And what would be the algorithm or possible approach to do so?

Comment: Also perhaps you could explain in an answer as to why there cannot be a Boolean algebra with 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: a finite Boolean algebra must have $2^n$ elements for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (and of course any power of $2$ is attainable, by taking the power set of an $n$-element set).  In fact, every finite Boolean algebra is isomorphic to the power set of some set.  As a sketch of a proof, if $B$ is a finite Boolean algebra, let $S\subset B$ be the set of atoms (minimal nonzero elements).  Then the map taking $b\in B$ to the set of $s\in S$ such that $s\leq b$ is an isomorphism from $B$ to $P(S)$.

For infinite Boolean algebras, any cardinality is possible.  For instance, if $S$ is any infinite set, the Boolean algebra of subsets of $S$ that are either finite or cofinite has the same cardinality as $S$.

Comment: Interesting. What is the operation you are going to define for the poset? $\subseteq$? Say I'm trying to construct a lattice with $8$ elements: I write out the set $\{a,b,c\}$ and find its power set. Then I guess the $\subseteq$(improper subset) relation on that power set defines a lattice?

Comment: Yes, the relation is $\subseteq$.